# How to concatenate string columns that contain NaN values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a data that looks like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

mydict = {
    'col1' : ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    'col2' : ['d', np.NaN, 'e'],
    'col3' : ['f', 'g', 'h']
}

mydf = pd.DataFrame(mydict)
```

I want to concatenate these string columns. I try this but it doesn't work:

```py
mydf['concat'] = mydf[['col1', 'col2', 'col3'].apply('-'.join, axis=1)
```

The error is `TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, float found`.

How can I make it work? It should skip the missing value and only concatenate the non-missing values. The outcome should look like this:

```
concat_dict = {
    'col1' : ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    'col2' : ['d', np.NaN, 'e'],
    'col3' : ['f', 'g', 'h'],
    'concat' : ['a-d-f', 'b-g', 'c-e-h']
}
concat_df = pd.DataFrame(concat_dict)
```

Comment: You can first do something like if it is ```NaN``` then it is converted to an empty string. Then you can do the concatenation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do your filter in the `lambda` function then do your joining.

```
>>> mydf['concat'] = mydf[['col1', 'col2', 'col3']].apply(
...     lambda s: '-'.join(s[s.notnull()]), axis=1)
  col1 col2 col3 concat
0    a    d    f  a-d-f
1    b  NaN    g    b-g
2    c    e    h  c-e-h
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply with `Series.str.cat(sep='-')`:

```
mydf['concat'] = mydf.apply(lambda x: x.str.cat(sep='-'), axis=1)
```

---

```
  col1 col2 col3 concat
0    a    d    f  a-d-f
1    b  NaN    g    b-g
2    c    e    h  c-e-h
```